# angularjs html5 mode pretty url not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am doing an angularjs application which was generated by web storm.
I tried to use html5 model pretty url (without # on url).It is not working.The url with # is working fine.
Here are my workouts
**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'MyApp.login',
    'MyApp.services',
    'MyApp.AuthenticationService',
    'headroom',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'angularSoundManager',
    'updateMeta'
]).
    config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'user/login.html', controller: 'loginCtrl'});
        $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
        // configure html5 to get links working on node-webkit
        if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
            //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); will cause an error $location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present! Unless you set baseUrl tag after head tag like so: <head> <base href="/">

            // to know more about setting base URL visit: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

            // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
        }
    }])
```

**index.html head section**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="content/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.css">
    <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

**login.js**

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('MyApp.login', ['ngRoute'])
        .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'MyAppSettings', 'apiService','AuthenticationService', function ($scope, $location, $http, MyAppSettings, apiService,AuthenticationService) {
            (function initController() {
                alert('d');
                // reset login status
                //AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
            })();
            function _login(username, password) {
                AuthenticationService.Login(username, password, function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {


                    } else {
                        alert('error')
                    }
                });

            }
            $scope.login=_login;
        }]);
```

Can anyone please help?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You set requireBase to false and yet put <base href="/"> in the head? Maybe the base needs to be at the top right after <head>? Check this site https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location quote: "Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a <base> tag is also important for this case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handled by the application."

Comment: It worked fine when i hosted app on iis.